# mediawiki query NOT IN syntax

Tags: database, mediawiki

I have a database query and I would like to add the condition:
`$not_these_ids = array(22, 34, 55, 66)
'page_id' != $not_these_ids;`

How do I write it in the mediawiki syntax? 
`
$dbr = wfGetDB( DB_SLAVE ); ...

$conds = array( 'rev_id = page_latest', 
'page_id' != $not_these_ids
 ); `
but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass an array of strings, one for each conditions, to the third parameter of select().

Example from maintenance/Maintenance.php:

```
            $dbw = wfGetDB( DB_MASTER );
            $dbw->begin( __METHOD__ );
```

[...]

```
            if ( count( $latestRevs ) > 0 ) {
                    $revConds[] = 'rev_id NOT IN (' . $dbw->makeList( $latestRevs ) . ')';
            }
            $res = $dbw->select( 'revision', 'rev_id', $revConds, __METHOD__ );
            $oldRevs = array();
            foreach ( $res as $row ) {
                    $oldRevs[] = $row->rev_id;
            }
            $this->output( "done.\n" );
```